# How to overwrite Ionic sass variables with driftyco:ionic meteor package

Tags: meteor, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

I use driftyco:ionic meteor package for my project and i want to change the "royal" color. Thats why, i want to know how to overwrite properly Ionic sass variables with driftyco:ionic meteor package.

Thant you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the driftyco:ionic meteor package results in a single CSS stylesheet that you can import.

In your HTML e.g.:

```
<head>
  <title>ionic</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>
    {{> hello}}
</body>
<template name="hello">
  <div class="bar bar-header bar-royal"><h1 class="title">Nice bar</h1></div>
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <p>You've pressed the button {{counter}} times.</p>
</template>
```

CSS, simply overwrite the classes you want to change:

```
@import '.meteor/local/build/programs/web.browser/merged-stylesheets.css';

.bar.bar-royal {
    background-color: #aa0033;
}
```

However, I recommend to make use of SCSS though, it makes your life much easier. Simply copy the [scss directory](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/tree/master/scss) to your project and use [this package](https://atmospherejs.com/fourseven/scss) to compile it.

Comment: I don't find the ionic.scss file with driftyco:ionic. Please, can you explain how to do this properly ?

Comment: @user3415686 Can you provide me with a "tree" of you file structure? How did you include Ionic?

Comment: I use driftyco:ionic   (1.2.4  Ionic Framework official Meteor package), i install it with "meteor add driftyco:ionic"